# MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard does not start for the first time

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I tried to install MySQL on my machine (win 8 64 bit). I downloaded `mysql-5.6.24-winx64.exe` and after completing the MySQL 5.6 setup wizard, MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard does not start and nothing happens.

In the Windows start menu for MySQL I have only 2 options:

- MySQL 5.6 command line client
- MySQL 5.6 command line - Unicode.

So what can I do to resolve this problem and run MySQL on my machine.

Comment: the service is not running?

Comment: @Masoud no it is not, after completing the MySQL 5.6 setup wizard, MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard does not start and nothing happens.

Comment: is service created?

Comment: @Masoud no the last step was:

Comment: mySQL server 5.6 setup completed but the next step (MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard  ) does not start automatically

Comment: @Masoud can u speek persian?

Comment: I cannot  Configure MySQL Server 5.6 server  Instance since it does not start automatically

Comment: You don't need the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard to install the service. use [MySQLD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html) to install and configure the instance